# Use POST method to get a field value from JSON

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

I need some similar help.

How can I get some field value from a JSON that some API provided me? Using the Post method

For example, I have an API

`https://api.comprovei.com.br/api/1.1/util/export/documentProcessTimes`

With the Json Below

```
{
    "headers": {
        "username": "usuario",
        "password": "senha"
    },
    "body": {
        "formato_exportacao" : "xml",
        "filtros": {
            "data_inicial": "2020-01-01",
            "data_final": "2020-01-01",
            "diretoria": ["String"],
            "especie_documento": ["String", "String2"],
            "regioes": ["String", "String2"],
            "transportadoras":["String", "String2"],
            "codigo_transportador": ["String", "String2"],
            "embarcadores":["String", "String2"],
            "placa_veiculo": ["String", "String2"],
            "tipo_rota": ["int", "int2"],
            "numero_rota": ["int", "int2"],
        },
        "campos": [
            "Rota",
            "Data",
            "Região",
            "Motorista",
            "Placa",
            "Documento",
            "Código cliente",
            "CNPJ Cliente",
            "Cliente",
            "Endereço",
            "Bairro",
            "Cidade",
            "Estado",
            "CEP",
            "Latitude",
            "Longitude",
            "Início de Viagem",
            "Início Pausa",
            "Fim Pausa",
            "Chegada",
            "Início de Descarga",
            "Fim de Descarga",
            "Registro da Foto",
            "Registro da Anotação",
            "Registro de Assinatura",
            "Fim da Entrega",
            "Tempo de Permanência",
            "Tempo de viagem",
            "Tempo de viagem + permanência",
            "Sequência original",
            "Sequência realizada",
            "Embarcador",
            "Volumes",
            "Distância Percorrida",
            "Pedido",
            "Base Origem",
            "Base Destino",
            "Data Agendamento",
            "Data Últ. Ocorr.",
            "Ultima Ocorrência",
            "Status Documento",
            "Transportadora",
            "Tempo de Espera",
            "Tempo de Descarga",
            "TMA",
            "Peso Bruto",
            "Gerente",
            "Valor",
            "Veiculo",
            "Janela Min.",
            "Janela Max.",
            "Ajuste Manual",
            "Usuário Ajuste",
            "Dia da semana da entrega",
            "Chegada dentro da certa",
            "Tipo Rota",
            "Data da criação da rota",
            "Data/Hora Ultima Chegada",
            "Campo Livre 1",
            "Campo Livre 2"
        ],
        "campos_inclusos": [
            "Início de Viagem",
            "Início Pausa",
            "Fim Pausa",
            "Chegada",
            "Início de Descarga",
            "Fim de Descarga",
            "Registro da Foto",
            "Registro da Anotação",
            "Registro de Assinatura",
            "Fim da Entrega"
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I get the value from the "Tempo de Permanência" field from an especific cliente or account and save this value in some custom field in my organization?

Why did they have this Filters("FILTROS") in the XML ?

Here is my code. But I am sure this is not the right way to do it.

```java
public class GetTempoMedioDescargaComprovei {
    @InvocableMethod(label='getTempoMedioDescarga')
    public static List<String> obterTempoPermanenciaCliente(List<Account> 
    accountIdList) {
        
        List<String> resultList = new List<String>();
        List<String> idList = new List<String>();
 
        String apiUrl = 'https://api.ci.com.br/api/1.1/util/export/docume';
        String username = System.Label.UserNameComprovei; // Rótulo personalizado
        String password = System.Label.PasswordComprovei; // Rótulo personalizado
       // String authHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password)); // Construção do Header de chamada de Usuário e Senha
         
        GetTempoMedioDescargaComTO.Headers headers = new 
        GetTempoMedioDescargaComTO.Headers();
        headers.username = username;
        headers.password = password;
        
        // Valida conteúdo da Lista
        for(Account itemAcc : accountIdList){
            idList.add(itemAcc.Id); 
        }

        List<Order> orders = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Numero__c, Placa__c 
                               FROM Order 
                               WHERE AccountId IN :idList]; 
        
        Date today = System.today();
        Datetime todayDatetime = Datetime.newInstance(today.year(), today.month(), 
        today.day());
        String todayString = todayDatetime.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
         
        GetTempoMedioDescargaComproveiTO.Filtros filtros = new 
        GetTempoMedioDescargaComproveiTO.Filtros();
        filtros.data_inicial =  '2015-01-01';
        filtros.data_final =    todayString;
        filtros.placa_veiculo = new List<String>{'String', orders.PlacaVeiculo__c};
        filtros.numero_rota = new List<String>{'int', orders.NumeroRota__c};
        
        List<String> camposList = new List<String>{
           'Rote',
            .
            .
            'Some values'
           
            // Resto dos campos...
        };
        
        List<String> camposInclusosList = new List<String>{
            'Início de Viagem',
            'Início Pausa',
            'Some values'
             
            // Resto dos campos inclusos...
        };
        
        GetTempoMedioDescargaComproveiTO.Body body = new GetTempoMedioDescargaComproveiTO.Body();
        body.formato_exportacao = 'xml';
        body.filtros = filtros;
        body.campos = camposList;
        body.campos_inclusos = camposInclusosList;
        
        GetTempoMedioDescargaComproveiTO requestDto = new GetTempoMedioDescargaComproveiTO();
        requestDto.headers = headers;
        requestDto.body = body;
        
        // Faça a chamada HTTP para a API
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(apiUrl);
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setBody(JSON.serialize(requestDto));

        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        String responseBody = response.getBody();

        // Analise a resposta e obtenha o valor do campo "Tempo de Permanência" do cliente
        // Aqui você precisará implementar a lógica de análise do XML retornado pela API e extrair o valor desejado

        // Exemplo de implementação simplificada usando o DOM.Document para analisar XML
        Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
        doc.load(responseBody);
        
        // Encontre o elemento XML que contém o valor do campo "Tempo de Permanência"
        Dom.XMLNode tempoPermanenciaNode = doc.getRootElement().getChildElement('Tempo_de_Permanencia', null);

        // Obtenha o valor do campo "Tempo de Permanência" como uma String
        String tempoPermanenciaString = tempoPermanenciaNode.getText();

        // Converta o valor para o tipo Datetime, se necessário
        //   Datetime tempoPermanencia = Datetime.valueOf(tempoPermanenciaString);
        resultList.add(tempoPermanenciaString);
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the JSON you've included in your question your request or your response? It would be useful to see the returned XML structure to help.

Comment: Your api doesn't work, so it's not possible to fix it for you. Also... are you sure you want to be exposing the username and password like this?